# Java MYSQL Nullpointerexception

Tags: java, mysql

Hey guys i'm trying to connect to my database and run a query. it all works apart from the query execution (after narrowing it down i found it to be this) Below i my code:

```
              Statement statement = null;
          ResultSet result;

           result = statement.executeQuery(query);//this is where error is being caused

           while(result.next())
           {
               Print("ID: " + result.getString("id"));
               Print("USER: " + result.getString("username"));
               Print("PASS: " + result.getString("password"));
           }
```

I get this returned:

```
database!java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Thanks for any help you give me

Comment: Icarus' answer was correct and should be accepted, IMO.

Comment: This is where I started with Java - http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query looks right. Surely the `statement` variable is *NULL* and you are trying to call executeQuery.

**UPDATE:**

Try this:

Statement statement = conn.createStatement ();

where `conn` is a Connection object. I'm sure you have one of those objects somewhere in your code.

Comment: You updated your question after I posted my answer. I'm glad I guessed. doing `statement =null; ` and right after `statement.executeQuery();` is obvious that will throw a nullpointerexception.

Comment: No, the opposite: It will never work! You are setting statement to NULL! You have to create an instance of statement before you can call any methods.

Comment: @Icarus how would i get it to work then? If i don't it throws an error saying I need to Initialize the variable.

Comment: @DuncanPalmer Set the `statement` variable to something other than null.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my problem by using a prepared statement:

```
           String query = "SELECT * FROM users";

          PreparedStatement statement = null;
          ResultSet result;
          statement  = conn.prepareStatement(query);
          result = statement.executeQuery(query);

           while(result.next())
           {
               Print("ID: " + result.getString("id"));
               Print("USER: " + result.getString("username"));
               Print("PASS: " + result.getString("password"));
           }
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: You're specifying the query twice so the preparedness of it isn't used. `result=statement.executeQuery()` will do.